# Creating a separate function to inject users in gatling

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a Gatling script with the following simulation which contain a few scenarios each of the scenarios contains an injection profile that is duplicated.

```
  setUp(
    script.create_learner_scenario.inject(
      nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
      constantUsersPerSec(UserCount).during(testDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes)
    ),
    script.put_learner_scenario.inject(
      nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
      constantUsersPerSec(userCount).during(testDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes)
    ),
    script.patch_learner_scenario.inject(
      nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
      constantUsersPerSec(userCount).during(testDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes)
    ),
    script.get_learner_scenario.inject(
      nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
      constantUsersPerSec(userCount).during(testDuration minutes),
      rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes)
    )
  ).protocols(httpConf)
```

Is it possible to have the injection profile in a separate function so that I can reuse it in each of the scenarios

```
nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(UserCount).during(testDuration minutes),
rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your different load profiles in `List`:

```scala
  val loadProfile = List(
    constantUsersPerSec(5) during (5 minutes)
  )
  
  val anotherLoadProfile = List(
    rampUsersPerSec(0) to 20 during(3 minutes),
    nothingFor(30 seconds)
  )

  setUp(
    scn.inject(
      loadProfile
    ).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as a variable using i.e. [`val` keyword](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/two-types-variables.html):

```
private val profile = scn.inject(nothingFor(nothingForDuration minutes),
  rampUsersPerSec(1).to(userCount).during(testRampUpDuration minutes),
  constantUsersPerSec(userCount).during(testDuration minutes),
  rampUsersPerSec(userCount).to(1).during(testRampDownDuration minutes))

// and then
setUp(profile)
```

More information:

- [Gatling Injection](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/)
- [Gatling Installation, Verification and Configuration - the Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-installation)

Comment: I was hoping to to something like the following, will this be possible 
 setUp(script.create_learner_scenario.inject(profile)).protocols(httpConf)